# wcf hanging on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am working on a test project to implement wcf callbacks, my code works when I am debugging locally, the callbacks then actually works, but when ever I connect to the live server it would simply freeze at any methods.

I tried all the Conncurency modes, I tried setting the timeout but it all failed

```
public interface IWorkplaySupportServiceCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void HandleData(byte[] buffer);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SessionCreated();
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IWorkplaySupportServiceCallBack))]
public interface IWorkplaySupportService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void CreateSession(string sessionId);
}

[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class WorkplaySupportService : IWorkplaySupportService
{
    public void CreateSession(string sessionId)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWorkplaySupportServiceCallBack>();
        callback.SessionCreated();
    }
}
```

And here is my configuration

```
  <!-- WCF START-->
```

```
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpFor2MBMessage" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2097000" />
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wsDualHttpBinding.SampleServiceBehavior"
    name="Workflowms.Web.webservices.support.WorkplaySupportService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpFor2MBMessage"
      contract="Workflowms.Web.webservices.support.IWorkplaySupportService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsDualHttpBinding.SampleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

By use of the Trace events I figured out why it is not responding, but I do not know how to fix this, the Client connecting is my Laptop and the Server is not on the same network (connect Via Internet), I added the wcf reference over the Internet but when I run it I don't get a connection, on the server Trace events I get the following exception
There was no endpoint listening at http://donald-pc/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/f9dbbcde-f968-48f1-bc48-e1e12dd13e32/6ca1305c-95e4-4248-a5f3-cbb594ea8a26 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work without any problem by changing

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpFor2MBMessage"    contract="Workflowms.Web.webservices.support.IWorkplaySupportService">    </endpoint>
```

To

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="netHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netHttpBinding" contract="Workflowms.Web.webservices.support.IWorkplaySupportService">
```

And Adding

```
   <netHttpBinding>
    <binding name="netHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2097000" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netHttpBinding>
```

Now my callbacks work in Intranet and over Internet